# SDL - Update Surface in C

Tags: c, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

i use SDL Lib and SDL_TTF Lib

I have a code that allows you to enter text
And then display the text on my window
so here the code

```c
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf", 25);
    SDL_Color color = { 255, 255, 255 };
    SDL_Surface * surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,"", color);

    
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_ttf in SDL2",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640,
        480, 0);
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);


    SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    int texW = 200;
    int texH = 200;
    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &texW, &texH);
    SDL_Rect dstrect = { 200, 200, texW, texH };
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
        
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    while (program_launched)
    {
        SDL_bool has_type = SDL_FALSE;
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            program_launched = SDL_FALSE;
        else if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_BACKSPACE && len)
            {
                rep[len - 1] = 0;
                len--;
                has_type = SDL_TRUE;
            }
           
            if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_v && (SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL) && SDL_HasClipboardText())
            {
                char *tmp = SDL_GetClipboardText();
                size_t l = strlen(tmp);
                size_t l_copy = len + l < LEN_MAX ? l : LEN_MAX - len;
                strncpy(rep + len, tmp, l_copy);
                len += l_copy;
                SDL_free(tmp);
                has_type = SDL_TRUE;
            }
            if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c && (SDL_GetModState() & KMOD_CTRL))
                SDL_SetClipboardText(rep);
        }
        else if(event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
        {
            size_t l = strlen(event.text.text);
            size_t l_copy = len + l < LEN_MAX ? l : LEN_MAX - len;
            strncpy(rep + len, event.text.text, l_copy);
            len += l_copy;
            has_type = SDL_TRUE;
        }
        if(has_type)

            surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,rep, color);
            texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
            SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &texW, &texH);
            SDL_Rect dstrect = { 0, 0, texW, texH };
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); 
    
    }
```

It's to (has-type) that I display the buff (rep)

But my problem is here:
[I can write and display in the window a text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM6rd.png)

But if i do a backspace and i write
[The texts overlap because the window, at least the rectangle is not updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qoDQ.png)

Is it possible to delete the content of my window (to display the buff without overlapping) ?

I use this documentation
https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.pdf
I had tried with this function: SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
But nothing helps

---

Compiler: GCC

OS: Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because once you've outputed something to the screen, it stays there unless you clear it or put something above it.

Think of it as a painter plotting things on his canvas. If you want to overwrite something, you have to overwrite the previous shape.

The simplest way to deal with this would be to call [SDL_RenderClear](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderClear) at the beginning of every draw, it clears the whole screen clean, and then every time you render something it'll never overlap the previous stuff.